# Single-Sign-On of ASP.Net to Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, authentication, single-sign-on

Currently, I'm working on ASP.Net project which will have user authentication in SQL Server. After authenticating user will get access to the reports the data for those reports will be stored in Oracle (data is available based on user rights and roles that are defined in Oracle). I would like to implement **Single-Sign-On** in my **ASP.Net**.

#### Here what I would like to implement:

- Use the MsSQL credentials to authenticate users in Web application;
- Map user's authentication information to an Oracle privileges table based on MsSQL.

Do you have any solutions, ideas or hints on how this can be solved?

Comment: I would suggest you look into something like MCV and the following
`app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);`